# Phonegap link within page not working

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, anchor

I have page in which has anchor tag. I have a button in the upper part of the page and when I click it I want the page to go to the bottom. So I have this

```
<a href="#clickmo"  data-ajax="false" data-role="button">Click Upper</a>
Some vertically long content....
<a name="clickmo">Click Lower</a>
```

When I click the Click Upper, it says 404 on the console

[image]

I even tried using `id` instead of name like so `<a id="clickmo">Click Lower</a>`

Not working either. My app is made of angularjs and typescript as well.

Comment: Could you try adding `target="_self"` in the `Click Upper` anchor tag?

Comment: It worked! You may want to put your comment as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `target="_self"` in the `Click Upper` anchor tag.